# Setting scroll position in ListFragments

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I'm trying to set the initial scroll position in a ListFragment, with no success. I'm trying to do the following:

```
public abstract class AbstractDiaListFragment extends ListFragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

(...)

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView mList = this.getListView();

        mList.setSelection(position)

    }
```

I've already tried using smoothScrollToPosition, and tried using onViewCreated() instead of onActivityCreated. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
            mList.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       mList.setSelection(position);
                    }
            });
```